# How to increase performance on google map for Android

Tags: android, dictionary

I wonder if we can get the same behavior and performance in own Andorid app with Google map? If you are using SDK (native development) the performance is diff to what you can experience while using last Google map from Android market. Are there any tips on it? I really like this smooth maps display while scroll up\down and labeling of street names, etc.

Comment: Don't draw a large number of markers in the onDraw() method. Definitely slows it down, as that method is fired continuously as you drag the map.

Answer (score 2):

No you cannot get same performance while displaying maps in your own application. There are a couple of reasons for it:

1. Firstly, the code that google uses is different and they are google if you know what I mean.
2. Your application uses google play services while google maps by google doesnot.

Answer (score 1):

> I wonder if we can get the same behavior and performance in own Andorid app with Google map?

Probably not. The Google Maps application does not use the same code base as does the Google Maps add-on for Android.

@Urban's point is very valid -- the more stuff you do in overlays, the slower things will be. An `ItemizedOverlay` with 100+ points, for example, will definitely be felt.

But if you create an app using the Google Maps add-on without any overlays, the experience you see there is as fast as you are going to get. Overlays of any sort will only make things slower.

Comment: Yes, I am just using Google Maps add-on on Android without any overlays so far, but the behavior is really diff from you can see on Google maps Android App. And I do not really get why? I assume that Google is using some performance optimizations in their own app that have not been published yet in Maps add-on or SDK. Am I right?

Comment: @user1076366: "And I do not really get why?" -- because it is not the same code. "Am I right?" -- by definition.

Comment: OK, but honestly I did not expect something like this as on the web it is the same behavior and speed.